# How can I solve this error, with BeanPropertyTarget?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, ant, wsdl2java

I do appreciate any help, I'm still new with Java and webservices.

The problem is: I imported a WSDL to my project, and when I consume it sometime it works fine and for another situations I got an error when consuming the wsdl:

```
ERROR [org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget] - Could not convert [B to bean field 'texto', type java.lang.String

 ERROR [org.apache.axis.client.Call] - Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXException: java.lang.ClassCastException@a39be8

. (stuff)
. (more stuff)
. (more stuff)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@a39be8
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.    apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor.set(BeanPropertyDescriptor.java:142)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget.set(BeanPropertyTarget.java:75)
... 73 more
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

I read about [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21482699)

*This issue can be solved when creating the client stubs with the -w parameter.*

*java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -w name.wsdl*

*The error will no longer occur.*

Is this applies to my situation? If yes, how can I do it? I'm deploying with apache-ant.

Answer (score 1):

> curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:(your action url)" -d@(request input file path) (webservices url) > (response output file path)

Use this command with appropriate inputs. If you get a proper output then you will have error when you are parsing the response.